# Google Apps Script - template statements to include external files not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use external CSS stylesheet.  However what I get is the '*** include stylesheet ***'  rendering in my html sidebar.  I created the include function in my code.gs file.  Why is this not working?

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <base target="_top">
 <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Form')
 .addItem('Open', 'openSidebar')
 .addToUi();
}
function include(filename) {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
function openSidebar(){
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
 htmlOutput.setTitle('Customer Inquiry Form');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}
```

**stylesheet.html**

```
<style>
 body{
  background-color:'gray';
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**At this function:**

```
function openSidebar(){
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
 htmlOutput.setTitle('Customer Inquiry Form');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}
```

You're using the [createHtmlOutputFromFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename) and it will serve the content of your **Index.html**, but it won't execute the [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) inside.

In order to execute the scriptlets you need to create an [HtmlTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template) and then call [evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate()) method, your function should look like this:

```
function openSidebar(){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle('Customer Inquiry Form')
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(template);
}
```

Also remove the `'` of the value `gray` in your **stylesheet.html**:

```
<style>
html{
  background-color: gray;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Don't have time to make the fix yet but I read the reference under template files and I see what you are saying is true.  I didn't understand at first and thought you misunderstood me, because you restructured my index file instead of the style-sheet.  But you are absolutely right, I need to use a template in order to be able to use the Scriptlet.  Thanks again, 2 for 2  :).

Comment: Ok.  I officially implemented it and it works.  Thanks.