# Google Script won't call CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

So I'm trying to get a program to call my stylesheet to format the HTML sidebar, but it's not loading properly.  here is what I have

```
addTime.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <?!= include('stylesheet') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="addTimeForm">
...there is more to the script, it's not needed though
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<?!= include('javascript') ?>
----------------------------------------------------------------
javascript.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

When I run the script, the `<?!= include('stylesheet') ?>` actually appears in the html box.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's actually `<?!= include('stylesheet') ?>`? I mean, this is not HTML standard... What is it? Where does that come from? Are you using some templating framework we should know about?

Comment: I got it from the Google Scripts reference stuff: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Comment: Oh, I see now! I've added a tag to your post. Maybe this could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39477092/5860648

Comment: Let me guess - you forgot to create it as a `HtmlTemplate` first and then return the result of calling `evaluate()` on it, and instead created an `HtmlOutput` directly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script - template statements to include external files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477092/google-apps-script-template-statements-to-include-external-files-not-working)